# replace enums with multiple extends sealed classes

Tags: kotlin, sealed, sealed-class

Currently I have three enum classes that represents states in my state machine and one to display operations

```
interface State

enum class OperationState : State {
    InProgress,
    Finished,
    Error
}

enum class FirstState : State {
    //some states
}

enum class  NextState: State {
    //some states
}

enum class  LastState: State {
    //some states
}
```

In my service I have:

```
 when (state) {
     is FirstState -> {
         //do something
         changeFirstStateOperationState(state)
     }
     is NextState -> {
         //do something
         changeNextStateOperationState(state)
     }
     is LastState -> {
         //do something
         changeLastStateOperationState(state)
     }
}

private fun changeFirstStateOperationState(state: FirstState){
    when(state){
        FirstState.A -> OperationState.Error
        listOf(FirstState.B, FirstState.C) -> OperationState.InProgress
        FirstState.D -> OperationState.Finished
    }
}
```

I would like change my current implmenetation to sealed classes.
I tried something like:

```
sealed class State {
    sealed class OperationState : State() {
        sealed class FirstState : OperationState() {
            object A: FirstState()
            object B: FirstState()
            object C: FirstState()
            object D: FirstState()
        }
        sealed class NextState:OperationState(){ ... }
        sealed class LastState:OperationState(){ ... }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work...

Is there any way, using the sealed class, to know what is current OperationStatus without mapping State to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? That compiles fine. Note that if every child of a sealed class is an `object`, it should be preferred to use an enum class instead for simplicity. You only need sealed classes when the children types need to be able to hold state.

Comment: Your `changeFirstStateOperationState()` doesn't do anything. It just declares things without setting any properties or returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This works for me](https://pl.kotl.in/QENg-fscu)

```
sealed class State {
    sealed class OperationState : State() {
        sealed class FirstState : OperationState() {
            object A: FirstState()
            object B: FirstState()
            object C: FirstState()
            object D: FirstState()
        }
        sealed class NextState:OperationState(){ }
        sealed class LastState:OperationState(){ }
    }
}

fun main() {
    checkState(State.OperationState.FirstState.A)
}

fun checkState(state: State) {
    when(state) {
        is State.OperationState.FirstState.A -> "it's A"
        is State.OperationState.FirstState -> "it's another FirstState"
        is State.OperationState.NextState -> "it's a NextState"
        is State.OperationState.LastState -> "LastState"
    }.run(::println)
}
```

Just note that you have to specify the entire type name (`State.OperationState...`) unless you do an import (probably recommended if you're nesting this much), and also you have to use `is` in the `when` matcher, because you're comparing types. You don't need it for the first one (`FirstState.A`) since you're comparing to a specific singleton object, so it's up to you how you want it to look